# Salvar uma entidade com chave estrangeira com Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Estou começando a estudar Hibernate e gostaria de saber como fica o método de salvar uma entidade com chave estrangeira. Segue exemplo de duas entidades:

### Aluno:

```
@Entity(name = "aluno")
public class Aluno extends Pessoa{
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String matricula;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String senha;

    public Aluno(String nome, String sexo, String dataNascimento, 
            String matricula, String senha) {
        super(nome, sexo, dataNascimento);
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.senha = senha;
    }
```

### Curso:

```
@Entity(name = "curso")
public class Curso {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int duracao;

    public Curso(String nome, int duracao) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.duracao = duracao;
    }
```

Agora a classe que contém chave estrangeira:

```
@Entity(name = "matricula")
public class Matricula {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_curso",nullable=false)
    private Curso curso;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_aluno",nullable=false)
    private Aluno aluno;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String matricula;

    public Matricula(Curso curso, Aluno aluno, String matricula) {
        this.curso = curso;
        this.aluno = aluno;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
```

Todas as classes tem *getters* e *setters* (não coloquei para não ficar muito longo)

Gostaria de saber como seria o método "salvar" para a matrícula. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia. 
O segredo para persistir uma entidade com chaves estrangeiras não está no método salvar e sim no mapeamento entre entidades. Para você conseguir persistir todas os objetos salvando apenas o objeto Matricula, será necessário que você alterar o mapeamento dos atributos Curso e Aluno. Deve ser informado que ao salvar o objeto Matriculo os objetos Curso e Aluno também serão salvos.

Para isso você devem o seguinte mapeamento:

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) //Com esse parâmetro na anotação @OneToOne você esta informando para hibernate que toda vez que você salvar uma matricula você vai salvar/Atualizar um Curso 
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_curso",nullable=false)
    private Curso curso;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_aluno",nullable=false)
    private Aluno aluno;
```

O parâmetro "cascade" exite outros valores, sendo assim oriento a você da uma lida na  [doc do hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html).

Segue abaixo um exemplo de método salvar no hibernate.

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     tx.saveOrUpdate(obj);
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

[SaveOrUpdate Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html)

Boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado, deu tudo certo. Ajudou muito, ótima explicação

Comment: Olá @Leonardo. Você pode indicar que uma resposta foi útil votando nela. Se uma resposta resolveu seu problema você também deve aceitá-la para que outros usuários com o mesmo problema saibam qual solução você acabou adotando.

Comment: A do Antônio Edmilson

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde a todos, eu estava com o mesmo problema aqui!

Resolveu perfeitamente:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```